# How to use a Set with Group by in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
Update Person
SELECT Person.person_id, MIN(donation_date) AS DonorDate, Person.person_isdonor
FROM Listing
inner join Person on Listing.fk_listing_person_id = Person.person_id
WHERE donation_date is not null
and fk_listing_program = 6
GROUP BY person_id;
SET Person.person_firstdonation = DonorDate
```

I realize this is a very customized question/request but I'm a hobbyist developer trying to help a local non-profit with some database upkeep and I've sort of fallen into their Mysql/PHP setup as the student has now graduated.

Comment: Basically what we're trying to do is, look up from Listing table a donation. Then, in order of their donations, list that as their first donation date.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks, I figured it out. I was putting way, way too much thought into it. I moved the "set" command into the second line and worked my way down with a where clause with 3 lines of "and"s. *Heavy breath.* :)